# Unable to edit my profile on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, profile-page, login, user-accounts

Whenever I try to edit something on my profile the changes are denied and this message shows:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile: This email address is already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our account recovery page to get access to this account.

I'm trying to edit my profile so I'm already logged in. I don't know how to fix it to be able to update my profile information correctly.

Comment: The linked question says to contact them if you have this issue.